# No puedo colocar valores de un formulario como inputs para un gráfico

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Soy un principiante en `Javascript`. Estoy intentando invocar valores que se eligen en un formulario `html5` que armé para que funcionen como inputs en un gráfico (todos los selects del form tienen id).

Estoy usando  [radarchart.js](https://gist.github.com/nbremer/21746a9668ffdf6d8242#file-radarchart-js)

Básicamente hice lo siguiente:

```
function myfunction()
{
var ANombre = document.getElementById("idx").value //Siendo "idx" un id de un select del formulario
```

// Hago esta linea por cada select del formulario (empleando sus respectivos ids) (Todos los values de los selects son numeros). Luego realizo una ecuación que debería retornar un numero tambien:

```
return ANombre+OtroNombre-Otro..... 
}
```

Coloco esta funcion como input en la parte que corresponde de la funcion que grafica:

```
var data = [
              [//inputs

{axis:"name1", value: myfunction()}, // Este es el input que uso de prueba, dejando los demas fijos para verificar

                {axis:"name2",value:0.4},

                {axis:"name3",value:0.3},

                {axis:"name4",value:0.6},

                {axis:"name5",value: 0.8},
] ];
```

Estos son los errores que me figuran cuando corro la web:

> ```
> Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNCNaN,NaN,…".
> Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN".
> Error: <circle> attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".
> Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN".
> Error: <circle> attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".
> ```

Comment: `getElementById` es la forma correcta de seleccionar un Elemento **Ojo con las mayúsculas**

Comment: Alan Borys has modificado el código, ¿funcionó arreglar el error ortográfico del método getElementById?

Comment: No, lo copie mal ahora cuando lo escribí, no es un tema de mayúsculas. Saludos